# Checking cells for exact match

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Long story short, we have a list of products on our website in CSV. All the product variants are assigned a colour. To save dev time, we've got it set up so that the `background-color` is the same is the variant name. Eg. `background-color: red`.

I'm wanting to take our list of products and say highlight all the ones that already have valid HTML colors. I've been able to do this by doing the following:

```
=regexmatch(C1,"Indianred|Lightcoral|Salmon|Darksalmon|Lightsalmon|Crimson|Red|Firebrick|Darkred|Pink|Lightpink|Hotpink|Deeppink|Mediumvioletred|Palevioletred|Lightsalmon|Coral|Tomato|Orangered|Darkorange|Orange|Gold|Yellow|Lightyellow|Lemonchiffon|Lightgoldenrodyellow|Papayawhip|Moccasin|Peachpuff|Palegoldenrod|Khaki|Darkkhaki|Lavender|Thistle|Plum|Violet|Orchid|Fuchsia|Magenta|Mediumorchid|Mediumpurple|Rebeccapurple|Blueviolet|Darkviolet|Darkorchid|Darkmagenta|Purple|Indigo|Slateblue|Darkslateblue|Mediumslateblue|Greenyellow|Chartreuse|Lawngreen|Lime|Limegreen|Palegreen|Lightgreen|Mediumspringgreen|Springgreen|Mediumseagreen|Seagreen|Forestgreen|Green|Darkgreen|Yellowgreen|Olivedrab|Olive|Darkolivegreen|Mediumaquamarine|Darkseagreen|Lightseagreen|Darkcyan|Teal|Aqua|Cyan|Lightcyan|Paleturquoise|Aquamarine|Turquoise|Mediumturquoise|Darkturquoise|Cadetblue|Steelblue|Lightsteelblue|Powderblue|Lightblue|Skyblue|Lightskyblue|Deepskyblue|Dodgerblue|Cornflowerblue|Mediumslateblue|Royalblue|Blue|Mediumblue|Darkblue|Navy|Midnightblue|Cornsilk|Blanchedalmond|Bisque|Navajowhite|Wheat|Burlywood|Tan|Rosybrown|Sandybrown|Goldenrod|Darkgoldenrod|Peru|Chocolate|Saddlebrown|Sienna|Brown|Maroon|White|Snow|Honeydew|Mintcream|Azure|Aliceblue|Ghostwhite|Whitesmoke|Seashell|Beige|Oldlace|Floralwhite|Ivory|Antiquewhite|Linen|Lavenderblush|Mistyrose|Gainsboro|Lightgray|Silver|Darkgray|Gray|Dimgray|Lightslategray|Slategray|Darkslategray|Black")
```

However, that's not finding the exact match. For example, it's returned things like Black/ White as having a match, which obviously wouldn't work as a HTML color. It's also found things like 'Swedish Blue', presumably because it's found the Blue.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is in the format as shown and you have another list, say in ColumnI, of valid HTML colours then select ColumnC and: Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... Custom formula is and:

```
=match(trim(mid(C1,19,len(C1))),I:I,0)
```

with highlighting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.